# Django filters form doesn't change the list of hotels

Tags: python, django, boolean, django-filter, searchbar

i have a search view that takes input from a search bar and returns a list of hotels in search_results.html

```py
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Hotel
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'hotels_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = HotelFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.session['myCountry']:
            self.request.session['myCountry'] = self.request.GET.get('myCountry')
            self.request.session['myCity'] = self.request.GET.get('myCity') or ''
            self.request.session['myDeparture'] = self.request.GET.get('myDeparture')
            self.request.session['myArrival'] = self.request.GET.get('myArrival')
            self.request.session['myPeople'] = self.request.GET.get('myPeople')

        country = self.request.GET.get('myCountry') or self.request.session['myCountry']
        city = self.request.GET.get('myCity') or self.request.session['myCity']
        start_date = self.request.GET.get('myDeparture') or self.request.session['myDeparture']
        end_date = self.request.GET.get('myArrival') or self.request.session['myArrival']
        people = self.request.GET.get('myPeople') or self.request.session['myPeople']
        

        results = Hotel.objects.raw('select h.id, h.single_rooms_number - coalesce(sum(r.single_rooms_number), 0) as SR, '
                                 'h.double_rooms_number -coalesce(sum(r.double_rooms_number), 0) as DR, '
                                 'h.twin_rooms_number - coalesce(sum(r.twin_rooms_number), 0) as TR, '
                                 'h.triple_rooms_number -coalesce(sum(r.triple_rooms_number), 0) as TRR, '
                                 'h.apartments_number - coalesce(sum(r.apartments_number), 0) as AR '
                                 'FROM globe_hotel h '
                                 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM globe_reservations WHERE  start_date >= %s or end_date <= %s) r on h.id=r.hotel_id_id '
                                 'LEFT JOIN globe_city ci on h.city_id_id=ci.id '
                                 'LEFT JOIN globe_country ct  on ct.id=ci.country_id_id '
                                 'WHERE LOWER(ct.name::text) = LOWER(%s)  '
                                 'GROUP BY h.id '
                                 'HAVING coalesce(h.single_rooms_number, 0) - coalesce(sum(r.single_rooms_number), 0) + '
                                 '(coalesce(h.double_rooms_number, 0) - coalesce(sum(r.double_rooms_number), 0))*2 + '
                                 '(coalesce(h.twin_rooms_number, 0) - coalesce(sum(r.twin_rooms_number), 0))*2 + '
                                 '(coalesce(h.triple_rooms_number, 0) -coalesce(sum(r.triple_rooms_number), 0))*3 + '
                                 '(coalesce(h.apartments_number, 0) - coalesce(sum(r.apartments_number), 0))*4 > %s', [start_date, end_date, country, people])

        return results
```

In search_results.html I also have some filters for the returned list, like: pool, wifi, restaurant etc. that attributes of the Hotel Class.

```
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'search_results' %}">
        {{filter.form}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button>
    </form>
```

I have the class filter based on some of the boolean attributes found in the Hotel class

```py
class HotelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Hotel
        fields = ('story', 'piscina', 'aproape_de_mare')
```

When submitting the filters form, I tried using the same view I used for the initial results because I needed the values entered earlier by the user to redo the query in the datebase and updated the get_context_data method with:

```
context['filter'] = HotelFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
```

I don't get any error, but the filters also don't do anything, my results are the same

Comment: And how do you expect Django filter to work on a queryset on which you have already used `raw`?

Comment: I am just trying to learn how to do it, but now that you said that, it does make sense. Should I create another view, should i try it here, I am just trying to figure it out. I tried it like this because i needed the filter to be applied on the list of hotels return by the SearchResults view

Comment: Django filter basically keeps filtering the same queryset `queryset.filter(...).filter(...)...` what you do is `Hotel.objects.raw(...)`. It's not logical to try that on a raw query right? You need a normal queryset for that. If there is no option other than using a raw query you will need to perform your filtering in the raw query itself.

Comment: I will try that and if that doesn't work I'll try filtering in the raw query itself. Thank you a lot !

Comment: I have a small question actually, maybe you can help me. I want to load the results after filtering on the same html page the initial view returned them. If I create another view, what would the url look like in urlpatterns?

Comment: Two views cannot serve the same request. Is the raw query you make separate from the filtering you want to perform? If so why don't you just pass the queryset yourself to the filterset `HotelFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=Hotel.objects.all())` while using the same view?

Comment: I did manage to obtain a queryset in HotelFilter. I put the result in context['filter'] but when I try to iterate with {% for hotel in filter.qs %} i get a tuple index out of range